# isSuccess for mutations in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm calling the mutation method as usual,

```
const [addTodo] = useAddTodoMutation();
```

So we have options like `isLoading,isSuccess,isError,error` from a query builder (From GET requests). But Can't we have the same options with mutations too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already there :)

For query hooks, the return value is an object containing `data` and the various loading/status flags: `const { data, isFetching} = useSomeQuery()`.

For mutation hooks, the return value is a tuple containing the "trigger" function as the first entry, and an object containing the status flags as the second entry: `const [trigger, objectWithStatusFlags] = useSomeMutation()`:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usemutation

So, just extract that object (and optionally destructure the fields from it):

```
// Either this:
const [addTodo, mutationFlags] = useAddTodoMutation();

// or this:
const [addTodo, {isLoading}] = useAddTodoMutation();
```